# What is the different between Ember-data Store's currentTransaction and defaultTransaction?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

General question:
**I would like to get an overview of current transaction (`currentTransaction`) and default transaction (`defaultTransaction`).**

Specific question:
I've [been comparing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309934/difference-between-model-save-versus-model-getstore-commit) in the Ember controller `this.get('model').save()` and `this.get('store').commit()`.

`this.get('model').save()` will eventually call Ember-data Store's `get(this, 'currentTransaction').commit().`, see [github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L943-L949).

`this.get('store').commit()` will eventually call Ember-data Store's `get(this, 'defaultTransaction').commit()`, see [github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L934-L941).

In the cases of updating a single edited record, they seem to be exactly the same. How should they be used differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to get an overview of current transaction (currentTransaction) and default transaction (defaultTransaction)

- **currentTransaction** is for records that were scheduled to be persisted, typically via model.save()
- **defaultTransaction** is for persisting records that were not explicitly added to another transaction

> In the cases of updating a single edited record, they seem to be exactly the same. How should they be used differently?

In that case they are going to do the same thing.

In general model.save() is probably a better choice, since 1) it wont have unexpected side-effects if there are other unsaved records and 2) calling save() on multiple models will result in just one commit(), making batch save possible.

Somewhat related:

[Difference between model.save() versus model.get('store').commit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309934/difference-between-model-save-versus-model-getstore-commit/17311778#17311778)

Comment: Hi Mike, since you are knowledgeable about Ember-data, would you mind looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499549/where-are-ember-datas-commitdetails-created-updated-deleted-orderedsets-set) related to commit? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, did this answer your question?