# Ember: how to retrieve validation errors after becameInvalid state?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use the RESTadpater to persist data. When a validation error occurs, I want to return a 422 response and then log the errors and show an indication next to each incorrect field.

My REST response status code is as follows:

```
Status Code:422 Unprocessable Entity
```

My REST response body is as follows:

```
{
  "message": "Validation failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": "duplicate"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my controller, the becameInvalid fires correctly.

```
App.AuthorsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  startEditing: function () {
    //Create a new record on a local transaction
    this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
    this.set('model', this.transaction.createRecord(App.Author, {}));
  },

  save: function (author) {

    //Local commit - author record goes in Flight state
    author.get('transaction').commit();  

    //If response is success: didCreate fires
    //Transition to edit of the new record 
    author.one('didCreate', this, function () { 
      this.transitionToRoute('author.edit', author);
    });

    //If response is 422 (validation problem at server side): becameError fires
    author.one('becameInvalid', this, function () {
       console.log "Validation problem"
    });
  }

  ...
```

**2 QUESTIONS:**

1. I want to log below the 'console.log "Validation problem"', the complete list of errors returned by the server.  How can I do that ?
2. In my hbs template, I want to indicate an error next to the relevant field. How can I do this ?

I am not sure that the data returned via REST adapter is correct. So problem might be at the REST side or at the Ember side ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

In controller save function:

```
    author.one('becameInvalid', this, function () {
       console.log "Validation problem"
       this.set('errors', this.get('content.errors'));
    });
```

In hbs template:

```
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='name'}} 
    {{#if errors.name}}{{errors.name}}{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it, may not be the best practice but it works for me:

1. instead of using commit(), I use save(), and if you wonder what's the difference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309934/difference-between-model-save-versus-model-getstore-commit) is the link. I haven't tried your approach of using transaction, but basically I create the record using record = App.Model.createRecord(...), and here is the code of my apiAddShop function inside the AddShopController:

   ```
   apiAddShop: function() {
   //console.log("add shop");
   newShop = App.Shop.createRecord({name:this.get('name'), currentUserRole:"owner"});

   //this.get('store').commit(); // Use record.save() instead, then() is not defined for commit()
   var self = this;
   newShop.save().then(function(response){
       self.transitionToRoute('shops');
   }, function(response){
       // if there is error:
       // server should respond with JSON that has a root "errors"
       // and with status code: 422
       // otherwise the response could not be parsed.
       var errors = response.errors;
       for(var attr in errors){
           if (self.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
               self.set(attr+"Error", true);
               self.set(attr+"Message", Ember.String.classify(attr)+" "+errors[attr]);
           }
           console.log(attr + ': ' + errors[attr]);
       }
       console.log(response.errors.name[0]);
   });
   ```

   },
2. the above code assume there is a attrError(boolean) and attrMessage(string) for each of the attributes in your form. Then in your template, you could bind the class of your field  to these error attributes, such as `<div {{bindAttr class=":control-group nameError:error:"}}>`, and the error message could be easily display next to the form field such as: `<span {{bindAttr class=":help-inline nameError::hidden"}} id="new_shop_error">{{nameMessage}}</span>` Here is my example handlebar [gist](https://gist.github.com/lionellei/6386735#file-new_shops-hbs) (have to use gist here, since SO is escaping my html inputs).